# Alternatives to Factory Method for large projects

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I was looking into different methods to implement a pattern that works in loading game save data. For example the player can save the game and it would save their inventory of different items and the type of character the player is.

The items all inherit from a superclass and when the data is saved the name of derived classes are saved into a file. When the data is loaded every data about the items should be converted into their respective derived class objects and stored in a `std::vector`.

Below is a rough example of what I am trying to achieve (There could be some errors)

Example Save file:

```
DarkSword
GoldenShield
EyeOfOdin
```

This is an example code file:

```
std::vector<Item> inventory;
std::vector<std::string> loadedInventoryData = LoadFromFile("exampleInventoryFile.txt");

for (const auto& textItem : loadedInventoryData)
{
   inventory.emplace_back(ObjectFromString(textItem));
}
```

My main question is about the `ObjectFromString` method. After some search on the internet I came across the **factory pattern** which required to make a factory class that returns the correct object using a switch-pattern but I wonder how big would this class grow if there are hundreds if not thousands of items in the game that need to be loaded in? Some suggest a hash_map but that surely also a lot to handle at a larger scales.

Is there a scalable method that would not require the programmer to work with a monstrous switch-block? What methods are used in large games such as Minecraft, World of Warcraft or Terraria?

Thank you and sorry if this is off-topic or in the wrong place.

Comment: a `std::vector<Item>` can only hold objects of type `Item`, not objects derived from `Item`.

Comment: a factory is the right choice. If you have hundreds of classes deriving from `Item` then you need to map the strings to the types somewhere, there is no way around that

Comment: why do you think a hashmap is to handle a lot? It will mean basically adding one line per type of `Item` when adding a new type to have the entry in the map

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for your tips. I was thinking it might be messy to handle with hashmap if the grew large. Then I would ask, is the hashmap factory more better than a switch method?

Comment: i suggest you to actually implement it and see what happens. It is natural that you would like to know before, but you will only know after you tried

Comment: Some variant of the factory pattern is the right choice.    There are variants of factory that can avoid having a big switch statement.    The trade-off of using hashes is that hashes aren't necessarily unique (e.g. there is a non-zero probability that two types can have the same hash) but, unless you have a huge number of types, the likelihood of that is small.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Factory is the right pattern.

No switch statement is needed. Usually a `std::map` is used.

The problem is often the need to use constructors with a different set of parameters. That, because the Object need to be initalized with different number of properties. But this can also be solved easily.

See the below example, which may give you an idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```